# Detecting Whether an iPhone has roamed from wifi to 3G or vice versa

Tags: ios, voip, 3g

G'day Guys,

I've been using the reachability API with reachability status callbacks to determine whether an application is connected over 3G or wifi. It's an application that acts as a voice extension for an existing piece of hardware and as such we're using the VoIP APIs to run in the background and accept calls etc.

Is there a definitive way other than using reachability status callbacks to determine whether you can access a particular IP endpoint or not? I could use an ASIHTTPRequest and then check if it timed out but that may cause potential problems for me in the long run.

I'm not looking for a programmatical answer but more any insights other developers would have on how to manage a roaming between the two in the background if you have a persistent connection. Basically if the device roams over to 3G I need to destroy the session on the device and if it roams back over to Wifi I need to recreate the session.

Any feedback or advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Reachability APIs will provide the connection change notifications to your app so that you can know when the connectivity changed from WWAN to wifi.  It will not tell you if you've changed from Edge to 3G or LTE unfortunately. The Reachability API also has methods to test reachability to a specific host.  So, in your app you can listen for the notifications that the connection method has changed, then when it does change test reachability to your target host and at that time make the decision whether to rebuild the session or leave it intact.